# Java dom4j org/jaxen/NamespaceContext exception

Tags: java, dom4j

I have downloaded [dom4j-1.6.1](http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar?r=http://sourceforge.net/projects/dom4j/files/dom4j/1.6.1/&ts=1350474200&use_mirror=garr) and added it to java's build path. I am also familiar with [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/saxpath/SAXPathException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10897922/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-saxpath-saxpathexception) but I keep getting an exception.

Enclosed a snippet:

```
public class Parser {
    public static void parse(final String path) throws Exception {
        final SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        final Document document = reader.read(new File(path).toURI().toURL());
        if (document == null) return;
        List list = document.selectNodes("/");
        for (Object o : list)
            System.out.println(o);
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get the following stack trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jaxen/NamespaceContext
    at org.dom4j.DocumentFactory.createXPath(DocumentFactory.java:230)
    at org.dom4j.tree.AbstractNode.createXPath(AbstractNode.java:207)
    at org.dom4j.tree.AbstractNode.selectNodes(AbstractNode.java:164)
    at Parser.parse(Parser.java:15)
    at Main.main(Main.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jaxen.NamespaceContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 5 more
```

Any clue what causes the error?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**The Exception:**

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jaxen.NamespaceContext
```

Maybe you forgot to include the `jaxen.jar` in your Java build's path.

For more specific instructions on using  SAXReader to parse some XML and loop through the nodes: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24959790/445131

Comment: Here's a link to jaxen dependency snipets for your pom, etc.:  http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jaxen/jaxen/1.1.1

Answer (score 2):

Found out the solution. I had to download and include [jaxen](http://jaxen.codehaus.org/releases.html) in java's build path.