# problem about dom4j when i want to parse xml document

Tags: java, dom4j

I get the following exception when trying to access any nodes of a parsed xml document on dom4j:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jaxen/NamespaceContext
    at org.dom4j.DocumentFactory.createXPath(DocumentFactory.java:230)
    at org.dom4j.tree.AbstractNode.createXPath(AbstractNode.java:207)
    at org.dom4j.tree.AbstractNode.selectNodes(AbstractNode.java:164)
    at xmlParse.XmlParser.extractElementText(XmlParser.java:56)
    at xmlParse.XmlParser.main(XmlParser.java:129)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jaxen.NamespaceContext
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
    ... 5 more
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java dom4j org/jaxen/NamespaceContext exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12933622/java-dom4j-org-jaxen-namespacecontext-exception)

Answer (score 1):

append Jaxen to your project runtime dependencies. Jaxen is XPath engine used optionally by dom4j.